# jQuery: add one collection selected to another of the same type

Tags: jquery, css

I have a collection of inputs selected like this:

```
$filter = $('input[type="radio"]:visible, input[type="checkbox"]:visible');
```

I now want to add another collection of inputs to $filter that are checkboxes that are children of a div with a specific class

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**add()**](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$filter = $('input[type="radio"]:visible, input[type="checkbox"]:visible');
$filter = $filter.add('selector-for-new-elements');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple groups you can also use $.merge()

```
$filter = $.merge($('#new-selector'), $filter);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amp7483g/